# Good Resources on SOA?

Tags: soa

Have recently been given a project to complete which uses XML quite extensively.Am looking at an existing project which uses SOA. Am eager to get up to speed on SOA and so wondered if anyone coulod recommend any good sites / books etc.

I have a book by Thomas Erl called Service-Oriented Architecture and am looking to supplement this with other resources.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a not so technical point of view there is this great book published by Sogeti and IBM called [SOA For Profit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9075414145) wich covers SOA processes SOA Governance quite well. Its a short interesting book that gives you another point of view. Then, depending on the platform/s you choose, each vendor will give you their point of view, for example if you choose Microsoft technologies, a good resource is their [SOA site](http://www.microsoft.com/soa/). IBM has another [interesting site too](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/solutions/soa/).

Answer (score 2):

[Infoq](http://www.infoq.com/soa/) has a lot of SOA content.

Like anything hijacked by the middleware venders you'll find a lot of discussion of SOA is dogma very distant from realistic evaluations of return on investment. Keep a critical eye.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late to answer. But still, I would recommend reading the following books to gain an in depth knowledge of SOA.
[SOA](http://www.soabooks.com/ctd/) by Thomas Erl actually clears confusion about how SOA is used as buzzword marketing agents. Also, He is founder of [SOA systems.](http://www.soasystems.com/)

Also, [SOA Design patterns](http://www.soapatterns.com/) is a good book to read.

Specifically mentioned the SOA again. So that others could get a direct link to it. :)

Cheers  :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these can help you too:

http://soa.sys-con.com/

http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/newto/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these ressources might help you:

http://soa.sys-con.com/
http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/newto/

Answer (score 0):

This 
   http://service-architecture.blogspot.com/> blog  has some sage advice on implementing SOA in large corporate projects.

Not hot on technical details but sopt on for design philosophy and how to do a succesfull implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the High Scalability blog. It's not just about SOA but surely any medium to large SOA solution can benefit from the ideas expressed there:

http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 0):

The book entitled Enterprise Service Oriented Architectures published by Springer Verlag goes into way more detail than Thomas Erl's book and is highly recommended.